# How can I uninstall a keyboard that Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator created?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

I used the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) to create a keyboard layout which I was able to successfully install. The problem is that I now want to update it, but I can't uninstall the old one.

The help file says:

> The .MSI is not written with 'Upgrade'
>   or other such scenarios in mind --
>   simplicity was the goal. Therefore, to
>   upgrade, you would simply uninstall
>   the old keyboard and install the new
>   one in its place.

it also says:

> Figure 4: Maintenance mode lets you
>   repair or remove the keyboard layout.

I followed the exact steps it shows and it even said that it has been successfully removed. However, when I go into the language settings, I still see it in there and when I try to make my new keyboard file, it says that there is already a layout with the same name defined. I tried restarting the computer multiple times. Reinstalling then uninstalling. Nothing works.

How can I remove the keyboard from the system so that it doesn't appear in **Control Panel** > **Regional and Language Options** > **Languages** > **Details...** > **Add...** > **Keyboard layout/IME:** ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally you can uninstall a keyboard using the following method:

1. Go to add/remove programs
2. Find the keyboard, it should be the same name as the **Description** field of the project's properties in Keyboard Layout Creator.
3. Press **Modify**
4. Choose **Remove the keyboard layout**

The problem was that I uninstalled it incorrectly and I had to manually remove it.

If you need to manually remove it, [here's how I did it](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-to-uninstall-klc-keyboard.html):

1. Remove the keyboard from the Language and Regional settings:

   1. Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Languages > Details...
   2. If it exists as one of the installed services, you should remove it. You can do this by adding another keyboard (e.g. `US`) and making it the default one, then removing the keyboard you are trying to get rid of.
2. Open **regedit**
3. Warning: you should backup your registry in case you accidentally delete something important.
4. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\`
5. Find the key that represents your keyboard: (referred to as "the key" in following steps)

   - It should be in the form `XXXXXXXX` (an 8 hex digit number).
   - Each key should have values such as: Layout Display Name, Layout File, Layout Id, Layout Product Code, Layout Text.
   - The `Layout Text` property should match the keyboard name that you chose.
   - Mine was near the end and started with an `a` instead of a `0` like all the others.
6. Take a look at the Layout File which should be a `.dll` name. I will refer to it as "the dll" in the following steps.
7. Look for the dll in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache` and delete it if it exists.
8. Look for the dll in `C:\WINDOWS\system32` and delete it if it exists.
9. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes` and see if it has a `Name` which is equal to the key's name (e.g. `XXXXXXXX`) and a value such as `en`. If it does, delete it.
10. Navigate back to the key (from step 5), and delete the entire key.

Comment: in windows 10 you can find your layout listed with the rest of the ordinary programs in Add & Remove

Comment: Also, check `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64` for the dll

Comment: The link http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-to-uninstall-klc-keyboard.html is broken. (And I couldn't find a good replacement for it.)
Maybe just remove the link?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that helped me to get out of this issue:

- Uninstall the layout via installer. This will remove .DLL files from appropriate locations but will leave keyboard layout record in the registry (and possibly DLLs already loaded in system memory).
- Log out. The registry will clean itself at this point.
- Log in.
- Rebuild and reinstall the keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

On my `Windows 10`, I had only to do 4 steps :

1. **Switch** and **disable** the keyboard layout in Language and Regional settings;
2. Remove the last entries of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\` corresponding to my Layout (LayoutXXX);
3. Remove the `C:\Windows\system32\LayoutXXX.dll`;
4. Also on 64bits, remove the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\LayoutXXX.dll`.